# Создание "слепка" CentOS 7 для разворачивания на другом сервере

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, резервное-копирование, devops

У меня есть доступ к серверу на CentOS 7 по ssh.
Мне необходимо создать "слепок" системы чтобы перенести("клонировать"?) не только файлы и права доступа к ним, но и вообще всё что есть в системе на другой, чистый, сервер(тоже с CentOS 7 на борту).
Подскажите какой софт я могу для этого использовать? Спасибо.

Comment: Клонирование можно произвести про помощи утилиты dd возможно Вам поможет https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-disk

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов, а `/sys` и `/proc` не помешают?

Comment: Когда мне приходилось делато клоны при помощи dd - не мешали.